# Can't access member functions in abstract class in Kotlin? Am I understanding it wrong?

Tags: kotlin

I want to have a class that wraps a few functions without the need to instantiate the class itself. Therefore, I figured an abstract class is the perfect candidate for this. However, it seems that I cannot call the member functions inside an abstract class even if I add the `open` modifier to the functions. Example:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    open fun showSomething() {
        println("Hello World")
    }
}

fun main() {
    MyAbstractClass.showSomething() //Shows unresolved reference
}
```

Please note that I am using Android Studio 2021.1.1.Beta.4 for now. Am I understanding abstract classes wrong?

Comment: At least in Java, `showSomething` would need to be static.  Try creating a new instance first `x = new MyAbstraction(){};`

Comment: @markspace Indeed the solution was using the equivalent of static methods in Java but in Kotlin, by wrapping all my functions inside a companion object. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a companion object and put the function in there. The `open` keyword only opens up the function to be overridden. All classes in Kotlin are `final` by default so they can't be extended unless you `open` them up.

```kotlin
abstract class MyAbstractClass {
  companion object {
    fun showSomething() {
        println("Hello World")
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can use it without instantiate anything:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    MyAbstractClass.showSomething() //Hello World
}
```

Comment: It seems like most of the tutorials are misleading. I always tend to to forget the use of static methods in both Java and Kotlin. Thank you very much !

Comment: The equivalent to static methods is the companion objects, as illustrated in the answer above.

Answer (score 3):

For your usecase you might not need to make any class at all. Just attach the function to an object. For example:

```
object MyObject {
    fun showSomething() {
        println("Hello World")
    }
}
```

This declaration can be put outside of classes on its own.

Then you can call `MyObject.showSomething()` wherever you like.

And you can actually also just define the function outside of any classes or objects like

```
fun showSomething() {
    println("Hello World")
}
```

and then use `showSomething()` wherever you like but maybe it's kinda bad practice to do it like that.